# Add trend line to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, machine-learning, statsmodels

I have time-series data, as followed:

```
                  emplvl
date                    
2003-01-01  10955.000000
2003-04-01  11090.333333
2003-07-01  11157.000000
2003-10-01  11335.666667
2004-01-01  11045.000000
2004-04-01  11175.666667
2004-07-01  11135.666667
2004-10-01  11480.333333
2005-01-01  11441.000000
2005-04-01  11531.000000
2005-07-01  11320.000000
2005-10-01  11516.666667
2006-01-01  11291.000000
2006-04-01  11223.000000
2006-07-01  11230.000000
2006-10-01  11293.000000
2007-01-01  11126.666667
2007-04-01  11383.666667
2007-07-01  11535.666667
2007-10-01  11567.333333
2008-01-01  11226.666667
2008-04-01  11342.000000
2008-07-01  11201.666667
2008-10-01  11321.000000
2009-01-01  11082.333333
2009-04-01  11099.000000
2009-07-01  10905.666667
```

[image: time series graph]

I would like to add, in the most simple way, a linear trend (with intercept) onto this graph. Also, I would like to compute this trend only conditional on data before, say, 2006.

I've found some answers here, but they all include `statsmodels`. First of all, these answers might be not up to date: `pandas` improved, and now itself includes an OLS component. Second, `statsmodels` appears to estimate an individual fixed-effect for each time period, instead of a linear trend. I suppose I could recalculate a running-quarter variable, but there most be a more comfortable way of doing this?

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 emplvl   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                    nan
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     0.000
Date:                tor, 14 apr 2016   Prob (F-statistic):                nan
Time:                        17:17:43   Log-Likelihood:                 929.85
No. Observations:                  40   AIC:                            -1780.
Df Residuals:                       0   BIC:                            -1712.
Df Model:                          39                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
============================================================================================================
                                               coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                                 1.095e+04        inf          0        nan           nan       nan
date[T.Timestamp('2003-04-01 00:00:00')]   135.3333        inf          0        nan           nan       nan
date[T.Timestamp('2003-07-01 00:00:00')]   202.0000        inf          0        nan           nan       nan
date[T.Timestamp('2003-10-01 00:00:00')]   380.6667        inf          0        nan           nan       nan
date[T.Timestamp('2004-01-01 00:00:00')]    90.0000        inf          0        nan           nan       nan
date[T.Timestamp('2004-04-01 00:00:00')]   220.6667        inf          0        nan           nan       nan
```

How do I, in the simplest way possible, estimate this trend and add the predicted values as a column to my data frame?

Comment: Convert the date timstamps to numeric values. The formula handling by `patsy` interprets the timestamp as categorical and creates the dummy variables.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a quick example on how to do this using `pandas.ols`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series(np.arange(50))
y = pd.Series(10 + (2 * x + np.random.randint(-5, + 5, 50)))
regression = pd.ols(y=y, x=x)
regression.summary

-------------------------Summary of Regression Analysis-------------------------

Formula: Y ~ <x> + <intercept>

Number of Observations:         50
Number of Degrees of Freedom:   2

R-squared:         0.9913
Adj R-squared:     0.9911

Rmse:              2.7625

F-stat (1, 48):  5465.1446, p-value:     0.0000

Degrees of Freedom: model 1, resid 48

-----------------------Summary of Estimated Coefficients------------------------
      Variable       Coef    Std Err     t-stat    p-value    CI 2.5%   CI 97.5%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             x     2.0013     0.0271      73.93     0.0000     1.9483     2.0544
     intercept     9.5271     0.7698      12.38     0.0000     8.0183    11.0358
---------------------------------End of Summary---------------------------------

trend = regression.predict(beta=regression.beta, x=x[20:]) # slicing to only use last 30 points
data = pd.DataFrame(index=x, data={'y': y, 'trend': trend})
data.plot() # add kwargs for title and other layout/design aspects
plt.show() # or plt.gcf().savefig(path)
```

[image]

Comment: note that ols module was removed in recent versions of pandas

Answer (score 9):

In general you should create your matplotlib figure and axes object ahead of time, and explicitly plot the dataframe on that:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pandas.read_csv(...)

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
df.plot(x='xcol', y='ycol', ax=ax)
```

Then you still have that axes object around to use directly to plot your line:

```
model = sm.formula.ols(formula='ycol ~ xcol', data=df)
res = model.fit()
df.assign(fit=res.fittedvalues).plot(x='xcol', y='fit', ax=ax)
```