# Best fit line for trend

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'region'  : ['a', 'a', 'a','a',' a','a','a', 's', 's','s','l','a','c','a', 'e','a','g', 'd','c','d','a','f','a','a','a'],
'month_number' : [5, 12, 3, 12, 3, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,2,6,7,8,3, 4, 7, 6,7,8,8],
'score' : [2.5, 5, 3.5, 2.5, 5.5, 3.5,2,3.5,4,2,1.5,1,1.5,4,5.5,2,3,1,2,3.5,4,2,3.5,3,4]})
```

I want to calculate the mean of the score in a region and create its trend over the year, as last I want to have a line of best fit to see if the trend is rising or falling over time.
(Not for predicted values, simply on the mean)

I filtered a region 'a':

```
filtered = df[(df['region'] == 'a')]
```

And created a trend:

```
filtered.groupby(['month_number','region']).mean()['score'].unstack().plot(figsize=(10,6))
```

This give the following:
[image]

Now I am stuck at the part how to fit the best line over the trend. My goal after all is to create a column with values of plus's or minus's indicating rising or falling trend in that region. If there is any other approach to this, I would like to hear it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add trend line to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627442/add-trend-line-to-pandas)

Comment: @G.Anderson: Please note that `ols` module which is used in the linked answer is no longer existing in pandas.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Stupid of me not to check. Thanks @Bazingaa

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just plot the straight line fit, use Seaborn.

However, if, you want to calculate the straight line fit for the data, use `numpy.polyfit`.

```
import numpy as np
f1 = filtered.groupby('month_number').mean().reset_index()
x = f1.month_number.values
y = f1.score.values
m, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

You have calculated the slope and the y-intercept for your point.

You can calculate points above and below your positions as follows:

```
yHat = m*x + c
yError = y - yHat
```

For your new column, just use the error values:

```
f1['HiLo'] = [ ('+' if m else '-')  for m in yError>0]
```

You will get your plusses and minuses ..

```
month_number     score HiLo
           3  3.500000    +
           5  3.250000    -
           6  2.750000    -
           7  3.166667    +
           8  3.500000    +
          12  2.833333    -
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [`seaborn`'s](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) regression plot `regplot` as following. The shaded region is the confidence interval.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'region'  : ['a', 'a', 'a','a',' a','a','a', 's', 's','s','l','a','c','a', 'e','a','g', 'd','c','d','a','f','a','a','a'],
'month_number' : [5, 12, 3, 12, 3, 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,2,6,7,8,3, 4, 7, 6,7,8,8],
'score' : [2.5, 5, 3.5, 2.5, 5.5, 3.5,2,3.5,4,2,1.5,1,1.5,4,5.5,2,3,1,2,3.5,4,2,3.5,3,4]})

filtered = df[(df['region'] == 'a')]
df1 = filtered.groupby(['month_number','region']).mean()['score'].unstack()
sns.regplot(x=df1.index.tolist(), y=df1['a'], data=df1)
```

[image]

If you don't want the shaded confidence interval, you can use `ci=0` as

```
sns.regplot(x=df1.index.tolist(), y=df1['a'], data=df1, ci=0)
```

[image]