# Plot many plots for each unique Value of one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So, I am working with a Dataframe where there are around 20 columns, but only three columns are really of importance.

| Index | ID | Date | Time_difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-40-50 | 2021-12-01 16:54:00 | 0 days 00:12:00 |
| 2 | 01-10 | 2021-10-11 13:28:00 | 2 days 00:26:00 |
| 3 | 03-48-58 | 2021-11-05 16:54:00 | 2 days 00:26:00 |
| 4 | 01-40-50 | 2021-12-06 19:34:00 | 7 days 00:26:00 |
| 5 | 03-48-58 | 2021-12-09 12:14:00 | 1 days 00:26:00 |
| 6 | 01-10 | 2021-08-06 19:34:00 | 0 days 00:26:00 |
| 7 | 03-48-58 | 2021-10-01 11:44:00 | 0 days 02:21:00 |

There are 90 unique ID's and a few thousand rows in total. What I want to do is:

1. Create a plot for each unique ID
2. Each plot with an y-axis of 'Time_difference' and a x-axis of 'date'
3. Each plot with a trendline
4. Optimally a plot that has the average of all other plots

Would appreciate any input as to how to start this! Thank you!

Comment: Q1 en 2: Perform a [group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the ID's, and then [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) the data that you want for each group. Q3: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627442/add-trend-line-to-pandas) post shows how to add a trend line using pandas, and for Q4, I am not sure what you want, but if you want to get the average per date, just perform a groupby on the date and average those values.

Comment: Let's say I do it like this:

df_new = df.groupby('ID)').nunique()

Right now I'm only possible to plot all at once. How would I plot 90 subplots(for each unique ID)  with stated y-axis and x-axis?

Comment: For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975835/how-to-create-pandas-groupby-plot-with-subplots) post. Alternatively loop over the groups and generate a separate plot for each of them. And another alternative would be `seaborn.FacetGrid`, see [this](https://tryolabs.com/blog/2017/03/16/pandas-seaborn-a-guide-to-handle-visualize-data-elegantly/#seabrorn) blog (long post, but interesting stuff is at the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

*For future documentation, solved it as follows:*

*First transforming the time_delta to an integer:*

```
df['hour_difference'] = df['time_difference'].dt.days * 24 + 
df['time_difference'].dt.seconds / 60 / 60
```

*Then creating a list with all unique entries of the ID:*

```
id_list = df['ID'].unique()
```

*And last, the for-loop for the plotting:*

```
for i in id_list:
    df.loc[(df['ID'] == i)].plot(y=["hour_difference"], figsize=(15,4))
    plt.title(i, fontsize=18) #Labeling titel
    plt.xlabel('Title name', fontsize=12) #Labeling x-axis 
    plt.ylabel('Title Name', fontsize=12) #Labeling y-axis
```